# Update layer Autocad Map 2014 from c#

Tags: c#, postgis, autocad

I use fdo and c# to connect to spatial data base postgis from Autocad Map 3D, when I insert a new element to a table , the database update attribute 'id' and 'id_rev' (primary key)  from a sequence, but in Autocad Map 3d 2014 it appears the new record with id and id_rev as nulls, and then i can´t modify or delete the entity from Autocad Map

Only when I execute update layer manually, this attributes obtain the new value, and then I can modify or delete this new record. How I update the layer from the code?.

I'd appreciate any help.

I use `layer.forceRefresh()` after of :

```
MgInsertFeatures insertarElementos = new MgInsertFeatures(featureclassName, propiedades);
MgFeatureCommandCollection comandos = new MgFeatureCommandCollection();
comandos.Add(insertarElementos);

layer.forceRefresh()
```

But, `layer.forceRefresh()` doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like the database has a separate table that contains the primary key and when adding new items you must insert the new id into more than one table.  See the autcad specification for more help : https://web.archive.org/web/20171013020945/http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2014_pdf_dxf_reference_enu.pdf